# How to send array of ids (stored in csv) in jmeter post request

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have getuserdetails api where I need to send purchased item in array

```
API: api/getuserdetails/${id}
Method: post
body: {"uname":{
"purchaseitem": ["121","11","4","12345"]
}
}
```

In jmeter setup looks like

```
>>TP_1
 >>CSVDataSet_ids
 >>CSVDataSet_purchaseitem
 >> ThreadGroup1
   >>HTTP Req
   >>JSR223 PreProcessor
 >>View result tree
```

purchaseitem csv has values like

```
1231
12121
312232
13
1
42435
133
```

I want to pass "purchaseitem" array values fetched from CSV in comma separated manner as shown in body

I've tried something like this in JSR223 PreProcessor

```
def list = ${purchaseitem}

for (i=0;i<=list.size()-1;i=i+10)
{
def mylist = list.subList(i,i+10);
props.put ("mylist"+i,mylist)
}
```

Can someone please help? Or is there any function to solve this simple problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something weird

1. You won't be able to use CSV Data Set Config because it reads the next value with next virtual user/iteration
2. Your code doesn't make sense at all

If you need to send all the values from the CSV file at once you should be rather using [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) class, example code which generates JSON and prints it to jmeter.log file:

```
def payload = [:]
def purchasedtem = [:]
purchasedtem.put('purchaseitem', new File('/path/to/your/purchase.csv').readLines().collect())
payload.put('uname', purchasedtem)

log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)